# How I should fix the following update statement to make it run faster?

Tags: oracle, index-tuning, tuning

I have the following DML:

```
UPDATE rc_usutb011 u 
  SET cod_ant=(
    SELECT cod_hst 
      FROM rc_pdptb101 p 
      WHERE ocip_hst=ocip_ant 
        AND p.sector=u.sector
    );
```

The explain plan looks as follows:

```
SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display());

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2656911336

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT             |                  |    17M|  1042M|    71M (25)|238:59:58 |        |      |            |
|   1 |  UPDATE                      | RC_USUTB011      |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX COORDINATOR             |                  |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   3 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)       | :TQ10000         |    17M|  1042M|  7632   (3)| 00:01:32 |  Q1,00 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   4 |     PX BLOCK ITERATOR        |                  |    17M|  1042M|  7632   (3)| 00:01:32 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL       | RC_USUTB011      |    17M|  1042M|  7632   (3)| 00:01:32 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|   6 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| RC_PDPTB101      |     1 |    61 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |            |
|*  7 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | I_RC_PDPTB101_12 |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |        |      |            |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   7 - access("OCIP_HST"=:B1 AND "P"."SECTOR"=:B2)

19 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.11
SQL>
---------------------------------------------------
```

My parallel configuration is the following

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM v$px_process_sysstat WHERE statistic LIKE 'Servers%';

STATISTIC                           VALUE
------------------------------ ----------
Servers In Use                          8
Servers Available                       0
Servers Started                         8
Servers Shutdown                        0
Servers Highwater                       8
Servers Cleaned Up                      0

6 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.45
SQL> show parameter parallel

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
fast_start_parallel_rollback         string      LOW
parallel_adaptive_multi_user         boolean     TRUE
parallel_automatic_tuning            boolean     FALSE
parallel_execution_message_size      integer     2152
parallel_instance_group              string
parallel_max_servers                 integer     40
parallel_min_percent                 integer     0
parallel_min_servers                 integer     0
parallel_server                      boolean     FALSE
parallel_server_instances            integer     1
parallel_threads_per_cpu             integer     2
recovery_parallelism                 integer     0
SQL>
```

Buffers:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM V$PX_PROCESS_SYSSTAT WHERE STATISTIC LIKE 'Buffers%';

STATISTIC                           VALUE
------------------------------ ----------
Buffers Allocated                      24
Buffers Freed                           0
Buffers Current                        24
Buffers HWM                            24

Elapsed: 00:00:00.07
SQL>
```

cpu info

```
SQL> show parameter cpu

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
cpu_count                            integer     4
parallel_threads_per_cpu             integer     2
SQL>
```

Please  help.

Thanks.

Comment: How many rows need to be updated (`cod_ant != cod_hst`) ? Is there a foreign key relation between the two tables (all rows from `RC_USUTB011` have a corresponding row in `RC_PDPTB101`) ? How many rows does `RC_PDPTB101` have?

Answer (score 1):

You're updating lots of rows. It will take time no matter what.

You could try to update the join though (since we have an `INDEX UNIQUE SCAN` on the lookup table), it will surely work better than an inline index loop:

```
UPDATE (SELECT u.cod_ant, p.cod_hst
          FROM rc_usutb011 u
          JOIN rc_pdptb101 p 
            ON ocip_hst = ocip_ant 
           AND p.sector=u.sector)
   SET cod_ant = cod_hst
 WHERE cod_ant != cod_hst
```

This is assuming that all records in `rc_usutb011` have an existing recode in `rc_pdptb101`. If this is not the case, you'll have to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN to have an equivalent query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem are not your indexes but that this statement will update every row in table RC_USUTB011  and that are about 17 millions.

How many rows should be updated?

```
SELECT cod_hst FROM RC_PDPTB101 p WHERE ocip_hst=ocip_ant;
```

I would rewrite the update statment in the following way:

```
UPDATE RC_USUTB011 u
SET cod_ant=(SELECT cod_hst FROM RC_PDPTB101 p WHERE ocip_hst=ocip_ant AND p.sector=u.sector)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from RC_PDPTB101 p1 WHERE ocip_hst=ocip_ant AND p1.sector=u.sector);
```